# Override system boot_id in docker

Tags: linux, docker, sysctl

My application checks `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id` and invokes some code to find out if this changed since last execution (stuff related to reading monotonic time). I'd like to test this behaviour in docker; however I can't find a way to set this:

- `/proc` filesystem cannot be re-mounted
- `--sysctl` has a whitelist of kernel parameters that can be overridden; `kernel.random.boot_id` is not amongst them
- running `sysctl` as root in the container won't set it
- I have not found any mention in manual page for `unshare` that would let me set this (contrary to the monotonic time that has its own namespace in cgroups)

I found mentions of `kubectl --boot-id-file` flag but I haven't figured out how exactly this would be applied. Any further clues how I could mock this? (besides extreme options such as intercepting the syscall with ptrace, or LD_PRELOAD for the open call?)